# How does one create a scope to find "Authors who have zero posts"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, arel

Using Rails 3, this scope works as would be expected:

```
      scope :with_posts, lambda {
        joins(:posts).
        select("authors.*, count(posts.id) posts_count").
        group("posts.author_id").
        having("posts_count > 0")
      }
```

The generated SQL is:

```
SELECT authors.*, count(posts.id) posts_count FROM `authors` INNER JOIN `posts` ON `posts`.`author_id` = `author`.`id` GROUP BY posts.author_id HAVING posts_count > 0
```

But its inverse returns no results:

```
      scope :with_posts, lambda {
        joins(:posts).
        select("authors.*, count(posts.id) posts_count").
        group("posts.author_id").
        having("posts_count < 1")
      }
```

I'm assuming that authors with zero posts are simply not being selected by line three... so what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the join is excluding all authors with zero posts, what you need is an outer join.

I don't know rails 3 syntax, but in rails 2, you can specify the joins statement with an SQL fragment instead of simply using the relation name.
`User.all(:joins => 'outer join posts on users.id = posts.user_id')`
Rails 3 must have an equivalent notation, but I never used it so I don't know the exact syntax. This should be the general idea though.

Answer (score 1):

Since inner joing SQL is being created it will show up the results with records available in both tables. So try creating outer join and find/count the null values in next table

**try outer join**

Answer (score 0):

```
scope :without_posts, lambda {
    where("id NOT IN (?)", Posts.select("author_id").group("author_id") )
}
```

This will work best if you have an index on author_id in your DB.